# PNM Sequence & asp.net: GridTemplateColumn should be mandatory

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I use **PNM Sequence**. And I need to make one grid column as the mandatory field.

I know how to make it with any separate control. E.g. I can type:

```
<sq8:GridBoundColumn DataField="txtField" HeaderText="txtField" 
     SortExpression="txtField" UniqueName="txtField" FilterControlAltText="">
         <ColumnValidationSettings>
              <RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor=""></RequiredFieldValidator>
         </ColumnValidationSettings>
</sq8:GridBoundColumn>
```

And I can use this Validator for the `TextBox`:

```
<sq8:Label runat="server" Text="Field:" ID="Label1" Width="100%"></sq8:Label> 
<nobr>
  <sq8:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtField" Width="100%"></sq8:TextBox> 
  <sq8:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
       ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
       ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" 
       ControlToValidate="txtField" 
       SetFocusOnError="True">*</sq8:RequiredFieldValidator>
</nobr> 
  <sq:BindableControl runat="server" TargetControlID="txtField" 
      DataField="txtField"></sq:BindableControl>
```

And it works. User can't send the form because he gets an error - the field is empty.

But I need to do the same with grid.

When I open `"Edit columns"` in `Grid Wizard` I can't see any property as "mandatory" or something like this.

And the code with `RequiredFieldValidator` doesn't work with a grid column. If I try to use it:

```
<Columns>
    <sq8:GridBoundColumn DataField="txtFieldGrid" HeaderText="txtFieldGrid" 
        SortExpression="txtFieldGrid" UniqueName="txtFieldGrid" 
        FilterControlAltText="">
            <sq8:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
            ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" 
            ControlToValidate="txtFieldGrid" 
            SetFocusOnError="True">*</sq8:RequiredFieldValidator>
      <sq:BindableControl runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFieldGrid" 
            DataField="txtFieldGrid"></sq:BindableControl>                      
   </sq8:GridBoundColumn>
</Columns>
```

In this case, I have an error:
[image]

Is there some method for grid column validation? Or it's impossible with a grid?
Maybe I can use some javascript?